# C++ covariance in parameters

Tags: c++, virtual, covariance

I wanted to know why C++ does not support co-variance in parameters like in example below or if there is a way to achieve it?

```
class base {
public:
virtual base* func(base * ptr) { return new base(); }
};

class derived : public base {
 public:
 virtual derived* func(derived * ptr) override { return new derived(); } //not allowed
};
```

Comment: A more interesting question would be why is contra-variance on the arguments not supported.

Comment: Related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53655187/c-covariance-or-contravariance-in-parameters

Comment: My guess is, this is a function that will be called rarely. If so, use a `dynamic_cast<derived*>` to get the derived value; this also gives you a chance to throw an exception for a bad argument.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The return type is permissible since `derived` inherits from `base`, but the function parameter can't work - not all `base` instances will be a `derived` also.  What's supposed to happen in the cases where `func` is called on a pointer to `base` with a parameter that's not a `derived`? The most derived implementation isn't callable.

Comment: Which violates the liskov substitution principle.

Comment: Is there a workaround ? In Java/C# you can just use a cast but in C++, your object will be sliced.

Comment: @Winter there is no slicing unless you pass by value (and pass by value would be weird with polymorphic functions which is the question here). Pass by pointer (as in the question) or reference/shared_ptr/unique_ptr will all work and be castable without any slicing as with any other OO language. The only question is which cast to use to guarantee safety and fit your type hierarchy which boils down to a choice between either dynamic_cast or static_cast and a stern warning to users not to break the unwritten contract you're imposing. Possibly you want to revisit your design decisions though.