# C++ contravariance in parameters

Tags: c++, parameters, virtual, covariance, contravariance

Why doesn't C++ support contravariance in overridden virtual method parameters ?

```
    class base {
     virtual void func(ParamDerived* ptr) { return; }
    };

    class derived : public base {
     // Shouldn't that be a valid override !?
     virtual void func(ParamBase* ptr) override { return; }
    };
```

Comment: They are not the same type.

Comment: pointer casts between parent and child classes do not necessarily compile to no-ops.