# How do I properly derive from a nested struct?

Tags: c++, templates, polymorphism, derived-class

I have an abstract (templated) class that I want to have its own return type `InferenceData`.

```
template <typename StateType>
class Model {
public:
    struct InferenceData;
    virtual InferenceData inference () = 0;
};
```

Now below is an attempt to derive from it

```
template <typename StateType>
class MonteCarlo : public Model<StateType> {
public:
    
    // struct InferenceData {};
    
    typename MonteCarlo::InferenceData inference () {
        typename MonteCarlo::InferenceData x;
        return x;
    }
};
```

This works, but only because the definition of `MonteCarlo::InferenceData` is commented out. If it is not commented, I get invalid covariant return type error. I want each `ModelDerivation<StateType>::InferenceData`
to be its own type and have its own implementation as a struct. How do I achieve this?

Comment: How do you plan to use the `InterfaceData` returned by `interface`?  Currently, even if it worked, anyone who called `interface` would have no clue what the thing it returned looks like.

Comment: You need to change Model::inference() to return a pointer (or reference) to `InferenceData`. Then you need to derive each sepcific `InferenceData` from `Model::InferenceData` and return a pointer (or ref) to it from each specific derived `inference()` method.

Comment: Thanks @wohlstad I forgot to derive the InferenceData. Is it really the case that this co-variance like this is only possible as pointers/refs at the return type? I tried using InferenceData in the arg and its not matching with the virtual function so I get abstract class initialization error

Comment: @RyanKeathley added an answer with a complete example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot change the return type of a derived virtual method.
This is why your compilation failed when you try to return your derived `InferenceData` from `MonteCarlo::inference()`.

In order to achieve what you need, you need to use a **polymorphic** return type, which requires **pointer/reference semantics**.
For this your derived `InferenceData` will have to inherit the base `InferenceData`, and `inference()` should return a pointer/reference to the base `InferenceData`.

One way to do it is with a smart pointer - e.g. a [`std::unique_ptr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr) - see the code below:

```
#include <memory>

template <typename StateType>
class Model {
public:
    struct InferenceData {};
    virtual std::unique_ptr<InferenceData> inference() = 0;
};


template <typename StateType>
class MonteCarlo : public Model<StateType> {
public:
    struct InferenceDataSpecific : public Model<StateType>::InferenceData {};

    virtual std::unique_ptr<Model::InferenceData> inference() {
        return std::make_unique<InferenceDataSpecific>();
    }
};

int main()
{
    MonteCarlo<int> m;
    auto d = m.inference();
    return 0;
}
```

Note: if you need to share the data, you can use a [`std::shared_ptr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr).

Comment: this is so close but due to performance concerns I don't want to use new. I want to pass a reference to an InferenceData object that is on the stack and change in place, or at the very least pass it by value since it is usually pretty light.

Comment: Nvm https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11821158/c-covariance-in-parameters has the missing piece. Now I can make the return void and pass a ptr to something on the stack

Comment: You can add a member to `MonteCarlo`: `InferenceDataSpecific  m_curData;`, and instead of returning a smart pointer from `inference()` return a `InferenceData&` with a ref to the member.

Comment: @RyanKeathley I'm not sure I understood you, but returning a pointer to something on the stack is a bad idea (dangling pointer). Better return a pointer/reference to a data member.

Comment: The member and reference return type are good ideas. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You have to make the return type part of the template arguments:

```
template <typename StateType, typename InferenceData>
class Model {
public:
    virtual InferenceData inference () = 0;
};
```

Then you can set the return type when you derive from it.

Comment: I don't really accept this since I feel I shouldn't have to specify inference type since its tied to the DerivedModel<StateType> type.

Comment: If you want them tied together then you can always return a `StateType::InferenceData`. That's hiding the second template argument as part of the first tieing them together. Not uncommon. But either way is the only way to return the data by value. If you return by pointer or reference then you can return a derived classs of `InferenceData` in the derived class.

Answer (score 1):

You can actually have your `MonteCarlo::inference` return a pointer (or reference) to a `MonteCarlo::InferenceData`, as long as you do things correctly otherwise. A simple version looks like this:

```cpp
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>

template <typename StateType>
class Model {
public:
    // base return type:
    struct InferenceData { };

    virtual InferenceData *inference() = 0;
};

template <typename StateType>
class MonteCarlo : public Model<StateType> {
public:
    // derived return type must be derived from base return type:
    struct InferenceData : public ::Model<StateType>::InferenceData { };

    InferenceData *inference() { return new InferenceData; }
};

int main() {
    MonteCarlo<int> mci;
    auto v = mci.inference();
}
```

This a a covariant return type (as the compiler alluded to in its error message). There are a couple of points to keep in mind here though:

1. The return type really does have to be covariant. That is, the base class function has to be declared to return a pointer/reference to some base class, and the derived function has to return a pointer/reference to a type derived from that that the base function returns.
2. A `unique_ptr<Derived>` allows implicit conversion to `unique_ptr<Base>`, assuming `Derived` is derived from `Base`, but a `unique_ptr<Derived>` still isn't actually derived from `unique_ptr<Base>`, so you can't use (most typical) smart pointers for covariant returns.

For the moment, I've used `new` to create the returned object. That's pretty common when dealing with derivation and such, but it can be avoided if necessary. Doing that can get non-trivial in itself, depending on your needs. In a really simple case, define a static object of the correct type, and return a pointer to it (but that leads to problems if you do multi-threading).

Comment: Is there any advantage of using such covariant return over the way I suggested in my answer (given that it doesn't support smart pointers well) ?

Comment: @wohlstad: The primary advantage would be if your derived class defines something new that a client can use directly via pointer to derived, that they'd have to use a downcast (e.g., `dynamic_cast`) to access if they receive a pointer to base.

Comment: Good point. Although if you use a polymorphic method like `inference()` you usually access it via a base class pointer/reference. I also assumed that although the inference data  might be different for each derived Model, it will have a common interface (inherited from `Model::InferenceData`). In this case no downcast will be needed.

Comment: @wohlstad: Yeah--it gets into all the usual "stuff" with designing an inheritance hierarchy. In an ideal world, you'd take everything needed into account when designing the base class, but reality often differs.